# How does `lsof` keep track of open file descriptors' filenames?

Tags: files, hard-link, lsof, deleted-files

I've noticed, if a file is renamed, `lsof` displays the new name.

To test it out, created a `python` script:

```py
#!/bin/python
import time

f = open('foo.txt', 'w')
while True:
  time.sleep(1)
```

Saw that `lsof` follows the rename:

```bsh
$ python test_lsof.py &
[1] 19698

$ lsof | grep foo | awk '{ print $2,$9 }'
19698 /home/bfernandez/foo.txt

$ mv foo{,1}.txt

$ lsof | grep foo | awk '{ print $2,$9 }'
19698 /home/bfernandez/foo1.txt
```

Figured this may be via the `inode` number. To test this out, I created a hard link to the file. However, `lsof` still displays the original name:

```sh
$ ln foo1.txt foo1.link

$ stat -c '%n:%i' foo*
foo1.link:8429704
foo1.txt:8429704

$ lsof | grep foo | awk '{ print $2,$9 }'
19698 /home/bfernandez/foo1.txt
```

And, if I delete the original file, `lsof` just lists the file as deleted even though there's still an existing hard link to it:

```sh
$ rm foo1.txt
rm: remove regular empty file ‘foo1.txt’? y

$ lsof | grep foo | awk '{ print $2,$9,$10 }'
19698 /home/bfernandez/foo1.txt (deleted)
```

So finally...

### My question

What method does `lsof` use to keep track open file descriptors that allow it to:

1. Keep track of filename changes
2. Not be aware of existing hard links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are right in assuming that `lsof` uses the inode from the kernel's name cache. Under Linux platforms, the path name is provided by the Linux `/proc` file system.
2. The handling of hard links is better explained in the [FAQ](ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ):

> 3.3.4 Why doesn't lsof report the "correct" hard linked file path
>       name?
>
> When lsof reports a rightmost path name component for a
>       file with hard links, the component may come from the
>       kernel's name cache.  Since the key which connects an open
>       file to the kernel name cache may be the same for each
>       differently named hard link, **lsof may report only one name
>       for all open hard-linked files**.   Sometimes that will be
>       "correct" in the eye of the beholder; sometimes it will
>       not.  Remember, the file identification keys significant
>       to the kernel are the device and node numbers, and they're
>       the same for all the hard linked names.

The fact that the deleted node is displayed at all is also specific to Linux (and later builds of Solaris 10, according to the same [FAQ](ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ)).